# Mismatched in actual number of classes and classes after test/train generator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, data-science

The **number of classes after test/train image generator applied** is different from the **original actual number of classes**.

- Initially, I have 4 folders (4 classes)
- After test/train generator I am getting 5 classes

Code:

```
input_shape = (128, 128, 3)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    target_size=(128, 128),
                                                    batch_size=32)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                                  shuffle=True,
                                                  target_size=(128, 128), 
                                                  batch_size=32)
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5ab82d751dd5> in <module>
      1 model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 2 history10 = model1.fit(
      3     train_generator,#egitim verileri
      4     steps_per_epoch=None,
      5     epochs=10,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is with the number of classes? The code you posted is totally fine - tested it locally.
Please, add the code that fails.
It also might be a hidden folder. Don't you have it? Try creating a new folder and copying subfolders to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible code to understand and fix the issue.